# How to start the horizontal line of text field in the bottom from the image(username)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, interface-builder

How to start the horizontal line of text field in the bottom from the image(username)? 
This is an image of output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 1px `UIView` under the `UITextField` and fill it with some color. Also, don't forget about constraints.